Material-Table is not displayed in the host React app
I'm trying to implementing Module Federation for my web app. I'm using React Vite. I tried to call <IdentificationCard /> component inside remote app from host app but it didn't showed up.
I use @originjs/vite-plugin-federation
vite.config.ts in remote app
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "remote-ekyc",
      filename: "remoteEntry.js",
      exposes: {
        "./IdentificationCard": "./src/components/IdentificationCard",
      },
      shared: [
        "react", 
        "react-dom",
      ],
    }),
  ],

  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false
  }
})

IdentificationCard.tsx in remote app
<div className="table-body">
  <MaterialTable
    columns={columns}
    data={data}
    actions={[
     {
       icon: Visibility,
       tooltip: 'View',
       onClick: (rowData: RowDataType) => alert("You viewed " + rowData.fullName)
      }
     ]}
     options={{
       headerStyle: {
         backgroundColor: '#F5F6F8',
         color: '#000',
         fontFamily: 'Poppins',
         fontWeight: '500',
       },
       actionsColumnIndex: -1,
       search: false,
       showTitle: false,
       paging: false,
       toolbar: false,
       draggable: false,
       sorting: false,
       tableLayout: "fixed",
       rowStyle: {
        fontSize: '13px',
        whiteSpace: 'normal',
        wordWrap: 'break-word'
       }
      }}
     />
</div>

vite.config.ts in host app
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [
    react(),
    federation({
      name: "host-app",
      remotes: {
        remoteEkyc: "http://localhost:5173/assets/remoteEntry.js",
      },
      shared: [
        "react", 
        "react-dom",
      ],
    }),
  ],
  build: {
    modulePreload: false,
    target: "esnext",
    minify: false,
    cssCodeSplit: false
  }
})

App.tsx in the host app
import IdentificationCard from "remoteEkyc/IdentificationCard"

function App() {

  return (
    <>
      <Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
        <Routes>
          <Route path='/' element={<Login />} />
          <Route path='/dashboard' element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route path='welcome' element={<Welcome />} />
              <Route path='identification-card' element={<IdentificationCard />} />
              <Route path='passport' element={<Passport />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Suspense>
    </>
  )
}

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you

set up lazy loading for your IdentificationCard component
const IdentificationCard = lazy(() => import("remoteEkyc/IdentificationCard"));


Tried that and it didn't display anything, just a blank page. Moved on to Tanstack table for the time being and it works just fine.
